# Is it real that USA military find specialists to help in specific disaster situations?

Tags: realism, science-fiction

In many Hollywood movies (specially movies with catastrophes like earthquakes, aliens, tsunamis, tornadoes...) military personal always wake up some scientists at their houses and take them (sometimes in pajamas) to a secret base under the earth where the scientists will usually solve the situation with some incredible solution in the end.

I would like to know if that is a real practice and if the government keeps a list of specialists to use in the most different situations, I guess it would need to be a national list since problems can happen anywhere within the country and USA is enormous.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about real life not films.

Comment: Isn't that what the `realism` tag is for?

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin: how is this different from other questions with that tag?

Comment: While I am quite willing to VtC questions, and was very prepared to do so in this case as well, I see there are over 400 questions tagged "realism" and its description is "The general attempt to depict things accurately in films and tv shows", which is in essence what this question is asking: is the common representation of the government conscripting help from technically-specific civilian persons realistically depicted. I would expect any answers to show examples from film and backed up with real-world examples.

Comment: Maybe skeptics.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for this question. Of course, if there is a claim regarding this question.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't they?
When coronavirus hit they didn't ring the local hospital to ask if there was anyone they could recommend.

Experts in any field can suddenly find themselves in the front line if that expertise is unexpectedly called-on.
It only makes sense to know where your experts are. Perhaps sending the military round is a bit larger than life, unless they needed them to fly off by helicopter to the secret base where they'd already been anticipating such a crisis… ;)

In the UK, one ready-made source for virology researchers was the military research facility at [Porton Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porton_Down), which started out in 1916 as a War Department experimental station & is now, amongst other still secret things, part of the home of Public Health England; one of the government research sources deeply involved in the study of coronavirus.
No doubt there are others, this one is just well-known. Research academics will all be networked & known within their own field. Just because the ordinary man in the street doesn't know where to look doesn't mean the 'industry' itself doesn't.

Comment: When coronavirus hit they didn’t go find virologists. They already had them in staff at the CDC and other places. Basically, for any national crisis, there are almost certainly already many federal government employees and contractors who are experts in the area. The areas of expertise commanded by various employees in the intelligence community alone are staggering.